# Dynamic bulleted list

Tags: jquery

This is what I'm trying to do but I'm a jquery rookie.

When the page loads I have jquery calls
`levelone.php` which print something like `BEACH{!}OFFICE{!}HOME{!}`
and creates my first bullet level.

When clicking on a bullet how can I call
`leveltwo.php?lvlone=HOME` which would create new bullets with
something like: `BED ROOM{!}KITCHEN{!}` and so on

Same on the new bullets
`levelthree.php?lvlone=HOME&lvltwo=KITCHEN` which would create new bullets with
something like: `TABLE{!}CHAIR{!}` and so on

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("load_locations.php", function( my_var ) {
        var my_varspl = my_var.split('{!}');
        $('#myDiv').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
        for (var i = 0, e = my_varspl.length; i < e; i++) {
            if(my_varspl[i]!=''){
                $("#newList").append('<li>'+my_varspl[i]+'</li>');
            }
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: Sorry I haven't figure out how to format this correctly on here$(document).ready(function(){
 $.get("levelone.php", function( my_var ) {
 var my_varspl = my_var.split('{!}');
 $('#myDiv').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
  for (var i = 0, e = my_varspl.length; i < e; i++) {
      if(my_varspl[i]!=''){
       $("#newList").append('<li>'+my_varspl[i]+'</li>');
      }
  }
 }); 

});

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to completely replace the page content? Or just add them in the page? If all you want to do is replace the page with the new list, just set each item to a link. If not, the following should work:

```
<ul>
    <li id="home-wrap"><a href="" id="home" lvl="one">Home</a></li>
    ....
</ul>
<script language = "javascript">
//When the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    //and someone clicks a link
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        //keep the page from reloading
        e.preventDefault();
        //get the id (in this case "home") of the clicked link
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //get the level of the clicked link
        var lvl = $(this).attr('lvl');
        //set the name of the space you want to use jQuery to load the new content in
        var wrapper = id + "-wrap";
        //load the page you want (in this case, pagename.php?lvlone=home) in the list item wrapper.
        $(wrapper).load("pagename.php?lvl" + lvl + "=" + id);
    });
});
</script>
```

So if you click on home, it should load the page at url "pagename.php?lvlone=home" to the < li > that you clicked on. In order to add a second, sub-list, to the original list, "pagename.php?lvlone=home" should output another unordered list.
make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm trying to build the list as I go, not replacing the content... I tried to implement the above code, but not too sure how

Comment: I've expanded with some comments. Maybe that helps?

Comment: Do I add this to my original code or replace it? Also, can the click be on the bullet? so I could use the link to open the page in another frame

Comment: Well. If you keep the {!} separator, you will need some of your code as well. I would suggest storing it as an unordered list, in which case this code could replace your current structure.